# Will a voice teacher help me improve if I’m a bad singer?

Tags: voice, teachers

I want to learn how to sing despite me being bad at it. I love to sing, it frees me and brings me joy! I recently got a voice teacher. I know this is a probably a dumb question. (Probably because I’m anxious and don’t believe in myself) Will I improve my singing and eventually become a pretty decent sounding singer with a vocal teacher and persistent practice?

Comment: It seems to be the case that not _everyone_ can become a good singer, but since you recognize your limitations now, I'm sure you'll be able to tell when you improve. Not posting as an answer since this is anecdotal/speculation.

Comment: You'll certainly *improve* your singing with a teacher - who really will be the one to answer this question. Whether it'll be a pretty decent sounding singer, how can we tell? We don't have the ability to look into the future of a complete stranger!

Comment: What makes you think you're a bad singer in the first place? I was told for years by school teachers my singing was awful, and as a gullible child, I believed I was just bad at it (and since I loved singing, it hurt as hell). Years later I found out that the pitch they made us sing at was simply too high for me. I couldn't hold the tone because my vocal chords were strained and exhausted. All I needed was to sing lower, and hey presto, all of a sudden I'm nothing exceptional, but decent enough not to shoo off an audience as a solo singer-songwriter.

Comment: So whenever I hear someone say they're bad at singing - and I tell you, it seems that at least half of all people think that - I get very skeptical. Yeah, where does this come from? Got it from a reliable source? Seems that most of the time it's not true.

Comment: Do you actually have a vocal teacher right now (sadly, bonus points if they said you're bad at singing right now) and this is why you're asking?

Comment: No, they didn’t say that I was bad. I haven’t asked them, they might say average.

Comment: If a teacher **doesn't** help you improve then you're either going to the the wrong teacher or ignoring all their advice.

Comment: That’s a Good point!

Answer (score 3):

As long as you avoid damage to your voice (which is one reason why a teacher is a good idea) it is clear that you will improve with guidance and practice. And unless you have a damaged or malformed vocal apparatus there is nothing that should hinder you to develop your voice. Learning to sing is equally about developing muscles, technique, body feeling and getting rid of bad habits carried over from speaking. As such you being a ”bad singer“ does only mean that you are not there yet. But this can quickly change once you start to train your voice.

Finally as you said singing can be a very freeing and empowering thing, it can help you get rid of stress and bad feelings, so if you enjoy it you will have a benefit even if you do not become the greatest singer of all time. Singing in a choir can be lots of fun and socially rewarding. You do not need to be flawless to justify making singing a part of your life.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with my voice. So, I can improve. Thanks for responding! I will probably get better! My simple singing goal is to just sound pretty decent while singing a song and not sound terrible. You know, like, being good at karaoke, not be ashamed to open my mouth and sing, when I try to sing, people won’t say it’s terrible, and finally, I just wanna sing for myself and sound nice, because I love reading, learning and watching about singing! I’m so captivated by it! I probably will discover that I have a decent voice to sing with. With my teacher helping me!Thanks for your advice,Lazy.

Comment: "Learning to sing is equally about developing muscles, technique, body feeling and getting rid of bad habits carried over from speaking" is a great summary +1

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly worth a try!  Also, you could sing alongside other, better singers - join a choir or other performing group.  And just do a lot of singing!

Don't be discouraged if you can't copy the performance of your favourite singer, in their key.   They had to pick the right key for THEM.  So do you.

Usual disclaimer about practising so hard that it hurts.

Comment: It is worth a try! Thanks for responding! I have heard that some singers transpose songs to fit their vocal range? Because it’s just simply out of their range. Like a female singer transposing a song originally written from a guy. And I won’t practice SO much that it hurts! I just love to sing and wanna get better at it! :) Thanks guys for replying!